# Python Multiprocessing Manager - List Name Error?

Tags: python, list, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to use a Shared List that will update scraped information from  Selenium so i can later export this info or use it how i chose. For some reason it is giving me this error:
NameError: name 'scrapedinfo' is not defined...

This is really strange to me because i declared the list Global AND I used the multiprocessing.Manager() to create the list. I have double checked my code many times and it is not a case sensitive error. I also tried to past the list through the functions as a variable but this created other problems and did not work. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from multiprocessing import Pool

def browser():  
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    return driver

def test_func(link):
    driver = browser()
    driver.get(link)

def scrape_stuff(driver):

    #Scrape things
    scrapedinfo.append(#Scraped Stuff)

def multip():
    manager = Manager()

    #Declare list here

    global scrapedinfo
    scrapedinfo = manager.list()

    links = ["https://stackoverflow.com/", "https://signup.microsoft.com/", "www.example.com"]
    chunks = [links[i::3] for i in range(3)]
    pool = Pool(processes=3)
    pool.map(test_func, chunks)
    print(scrapedinfo)

multip()
```

Comment: Are you using Windows or linux? Try putting the call to `multip()` in an `if __name__ == "__main__":` block to avoid reimport issues in the child process.

Comment: It i s in a if__name__...i just didnt add that because my code is like 3000 lines bro. I am using windows btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows, multiprocessing executes a new python process and then tries to pickle/unpickle a limited view of the parent state for the child. Global variables that are not passed in the `map` call are not included. `scrapedinfo` is not created in the child and you get the error.

One solution is to pass `scrapedinfo` in the map call. Hacking down to a quick example,

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager

def test_func(param):
    scrapedinfo, link = param
    scrapedinfo.append("i scraped stuff from " + str(link))

def multip():
    manager = Manager()

    global scrapedinfo
    scrapedinfo = manager.list()

    links = ["https://stackoverflow.com/", "https://signup.microsoft.com/", "www.example.com"]
    chunks = [links[i::3] for i in range(3)]
    pool = Pool(processes=3)
    pool.map(test_func, list((scrapedinfo, chunk) for chunk in chunks))
    print(scrapedinfo)

if __name__=="__main__":
    multip()
```

But you are doing more work than you need to with the Manager. `map` passes the worker's return value back to the parent process (and handles chunking). So you could do:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager

def test_func(link):
    return "i scraped stuff from " + link

def multip():
    links = ["https://stackoverflow.com/", "https://signup.microsoft.com/", "www.example.com"]
    pool = Pool(processes=3)
    scrapedinfo = pool.map(test_func, links)
    print(scrapedinfo)

if __name__=="__main__":
    multip()
```

And avoid the extra processsing of a clunky list proxy.